# cd using empty string inconsistencies

Tags: shell, posix, sh, ksh, chdir

According to ["chdir" xopen specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html), using an empty string ("") as argument should results in an error (enoent):

```
[ENOENT]
A component of path does not name an existing directory or path is an empty string.
```

I've checked many different combinations of OSes and shells using command;

```
cd ""
```

which eventually calls "chdir" system call, with argv == 2, and argv[1] pointing to an empty string.

The results is that only some ksh93  (*not* all versions) on Linux (not on AIX) returns an error. "/bin/sh" always success but on AIX it moves to $HOME and on linux cwd is unchanged

Why so many differences?

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on [unix.se]

Comment: This was discussed recently on comp.unix.shell: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.unix.shell/J_5Wk84wO6w/xNiMUjrLCgAJ

Comment: @keith thanks for the link. The example given there:


    `cd "$var" || exit 1
    rm -rf something_important`


match *exactly* the source of my concerns regarding that issue.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested previously, you can trace through the [cd open group page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) to find the behavior (my notes are the bullet-points):

1. If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is empty or undefined, the default behavior is implementation-defined and no further steps shall be taken.

   - This is not true, as there is a directory operand, it's just a zero-length string
2. If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is set to a non-empty value, the cd utility shall behave as if the directory named in the HOME environment variable was specified as the directory operand.

   - See above
3. If the directory operand begins with a `<slash>` character, set **curpath** to the operand and proceed to step 7.

   - Again false, go to the next step
4. If the first component of the directory operand is dot or dot-dot, proceed to step 6.

   - false again
5. Starting with the first pathname in the `<colon>`-separated pathnames of CDPATH (see the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section) if the pathname is non-null, test if the concatenation of that pathname, a `<slash>` character if that pathname did not end with a `<slash>` character, and the directory operand names a directory. If the pathname is null, test if the concatenation of dot, a `<slash>` character, and the operand names a directory. In either case, if the resulting string names an existing directory, set **curpath** to that string and proceed to step 7. Otherwise, repeat this step with the next pathname in CDPATH until all pathnames have been tested.

   - Here's where we hit the meat.  By the specification, if CDPATH is set and a pathname in there points to a directory, it will find the first existing pathname.  So if CDPATH is `/foo:/bar:/baz` and `/foo` does not exist, cd will first try `/foo/` and fail this step.  It will then try `/bar/`.  If `/bar` exists as a directory, it will set **curpath** to `/bar/` and proceed.  If CDPATH is null, it will test `./` to see if it points to a directory (and it will, typically, because this is your `pwd`).
6. Set **curpath** to the directory operand.

   - In other words, if CDPATH is set but none of its components exist, it will just use the directory operand, which is an empty string.
7. If the -P option is in effect, proceed to step 10. If **curpath** does not begin with a `<slash>` character, set **curpath** to the string formed by the concatenation of the value of PWD, a `<slash>` character if the value of PWD did not end with a `<slash>` character, and **curpath**.

   - If we hit step 6, this will set **curpath** to the `PWD`, as it will be `$(pwd)/`.
   - In essence, by this step, if CDPATH is set and has an existing directory as a component, the first existing component will be what **curpath** is now, otherwise **curpath** will be `PWD` (or possibly `PWD/./` to the same effect)
8. The **curpath** value shall then be converted to canonical form as follows, considering each component from beginning to end, in sequence:

   1. Dot components and any `<slash>` characters that separate them from the next component shall be deleted.
   2. For each dot-dot component, if there is a preceding component and it is neither root nor dot-dot, then:

      1. If the preceding component does not refer (in the context of pathname resolution with symbolic links followed) to a directory, then the cd utility shall display an appropriate error message and no further steps shall be taken.
      2. The preceding component, all `<slash>` characters separating the preceding component from dot-dot, dot-dot, and all  characters separating dot-dot from the following component (if any) shall be deleted.
   3. An implementation may further simplify **curpath** by removing any trailing `<slash>` characters that are not also leading  characters, replacing multiple non-leading consecutive  characters with a single `<slash>`, and replacing three or more leading `<slash>` characters with a single `<slash>`. If, as a result of this canonicalization, the **curpath** variable is null, no further steps shall be taken.

      - Simple path canonicalization.  Interestingly, they account in the last step for if the path is left null by explicitly showing it as a noop, though I'm not sure how this could possibly happen, as all relative paths have PWD prepended to them before this step.
9. If **curpath** is longer than {PATH_MAX} bytes (including the terminating null) and the directory operand was not longer than {PATH_MAX} bytes (including the terminating null), then **curpath** shall be converted from an absolute pathname to an equivalent relative pathname if possible. This conversion shall always be considered possible if the value of PWD, with a trailing `<slash>` added if it does not already have one, is an initial substring of **curpath**. Whether or not it is considered possible under other circumstances is unspecified. Implementations may also apply this conversion if **curpath** is not longer than {PATH_MAX} bytes or the directory operand was longer than {PATH_MAX} bytes.

   - Doesn't seem to do much other than make the path relative again if it's too long.
10. The cd utility shall then perform actions equivalent to the chdir() function called with **curpath** as the path argument. If these actions fail for any reason, the cd utility shall display an appropriate error message and the remainder of this step shall not be executed. If the -P option is not in effect, the PWD environment variable shall be set to the value that **curpath** had on entry to step 9 (i.e., before conversion to a relative pathname). If the -P option is in effect, the PWD environment variable shall be set to the string that would be output by pwd -P. If there is insufficient permission on the new directory, or on any parent of that directory, to determine the current working directory, the value of the PWD environment variable is unspecified.

    - And here is where the chdir actually takes place.

## In conclusion

So in essence, a command of `cd ''` by the standard should cd to the first existing component of `CDPATH`, if it is set, or to the current directory otherwise.  If `cd -P ''` is used, it will also remove symlinks from the path.  In this way, `chdir` should only be called with an empty string if CDPATH is non-null, but none of its components exist, and `cd -P ''` is called, as that will pass through step 5, set the **curpath** to an empty string in step 6, then jump from step 7 to step 10.  I don't see any other way that chdir would be called with an empty string, unless a bad implementation takes step 9 too literally and sets **curpath** to an empty string following the last sentence.  ksh93 on Linux and /bin/sh on AIX are nonconformant by these rules.  In this way, I'd be careful about using a cd to a path that might evaluate zero-length, as a CDPATH being set can weirdly affect what you're trying to do (though CDPATH has unexpected and confusing behavior anyway, and should not be used in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples and pears here.

The xopen specification you are quoting, refers to the C-function `chdir`.

The two shells I'm using (bash and zsh) have an internal command cd, and in both shells, a

```
cd ''
```

is interpreted as a no-op. This is explained in the man pages, for example for bash:

> A null directory name in CDPATH is  the  same  as  the current  directory,  i.e., ``.''.

So this is the intended behaviour. Note that the standard you are quoting doesn't say anything about the shell's cd command.

I didn't check how the developers of bash and zsh actually implemented the cd command, but if they want to comply to their own specification, they must implement it (in C) similar to this:

```
if(argc == 0) {
    chdir(getenv("HOME"));
} else if(strlen(argv[1]) == 0) {
    chdir(".");
} else {
    chdir(argv[1]);
}
```

If it's not done in this way, the behaviour of the chdir command would depend on the underlying implementation of the system library (and, yes, on the conformance to the xopen standard), and *this* would certainly be a bug in the shell implementation (though a different one than you are referring to).

**UPDATE**: As *CoolRaoul* correctly noted in his comment, my quote of the bash manpage is not relevant here, as it refers only to an empty element in the CDPATH, not to an empty argument of the `cd` command. While it is reasonable to assume that the effect in both cases should be the same, this is not explicitly specified. The same is true for the zsh manpage. In both manpages, it is also not explicitly said that the cd command invokes the C function `chdir` (although this also can reasonably assumed), nor do they seem to refer to any compliance to the xopen specification. At least for bash and zsh, I think we can safely say that the behaviour of `cd ""` is simply unspecified.

BTW, I also tried it with the ksh which comes with Cygwin (and which identifies itself as MIRBSD KSH R50), and it behaves in the same way as bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Check section 4, *Shell & Utilities* of the IEEE Std 1003.1™ or [Open Group Base Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799).

This contains a separate [page for cd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), which says:

> The cd utility shall then perform actions equivalent to the chdir()
>   function called with curpath as the path argument. If these actions
>   fail for any reason, the cd utility shall display an appropriate
>   error message and the remainder of this step shall not be executed.

This would suggest that the ksh93 that fails on `cd ""` is actually working according to spec.  This is what I see on Ubuntu 14.04, ksh Version `AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01`.

Comment: For ksh93, according to my tests, the results are very mixed: 

Have a look: http://pastebin.com/raw/MmMHRpMv

Comment: @CoolRaoul Thanks, that pretty much conforms my findings, as only `ksh93u+` appears to exhibits IEEE Std behaviour.  I suspect the ksh team noticed the specification and adjusted the shell accordingly. They always were sticklers for standards.
- BTW, that ksh93 in Solaris 9 was never part of the official distribution.

Comment: _"ksh93 in Solaris 9 was never part of the official distribution"_

You're right: it's dtksh which I've symlinked to ksh on the few (and pretty outdated) Solaris hosts remaining in my scope for script compatibility purposes.